# Executing for loop with if loop inside until it's complete

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to accomplish the following thing in my python program:

```
for l in list(p):
    if condition1:
        S1
        s2
        s3

        if condition2:
            return something
```

What I want to do here that, is it possible to execute the for loop until it's finished and then execute the 2nd if loop only once. The thing is that the 2nd if loop has to be inside for loop and it should execute only once.

Please let me know if that's possible and how can I do it??

Comment: You need to rewrite your question. You only have one loop (for) and two conditionals (if), the '2nd if loop' does not make sense. I think what you are asking is how to write a statement that will run after the final element from the list has been processed but in the scope of the loop.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Where is and why does the second loop have to be inside the first?

Comment: `if`s are not loops, please rephrase your question

Comment: "wait until finished and then execute only once" is not compatible with "has to be inside `for` loop". Why not just put `if condition2` at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to move that code block to the `else` block of the `for` loop which executes immediately after the `for` loop is *exhausted*. The second `if` will be executed only once:

```
for l in p:
    if condition1:
       ...
else:
    if condition2:
         return something
```

The `else` block of the `for` will be executed provided there were no exceptions, `break` or `return` statements in the body of the `for` loop.

On a side note, if `p` is iterable, you don't need to call `list` on it before using it in your `for`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop with an increment counter i and index to reference the list elements. Then you can add a condition to condition2 that prevents it from evaluating unless i == len(list(p)).